# Resolving undefined in email URL

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

I am getting undefined on my link at the variable **productsList** in the url url any ideas of what can be the problem?

When I hover over the link it shows the string correctly but when its clicked it turns it into undefined

MY CODE:

```
$(".emailCustomer").click(function(urlEmail){

      var invoiceNumber = $(this).closest("li").find(".invoiceNumber").text();
     // active subject invoice no.
      var emailAddress = $(this).data("email");
      var customerName = $(this).data("customer");
      var productsList = $(this).data("products");

      urlEmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to="+emailAddress+"&su=+invoiceNumber+&body="+customerName+"%2C%0A%0A"+productsList+"%0A%0AEMAIL+SIGNATURE";
      $(this).attr("href" , urlEmail); 
      $(this).attr("target" , "_blank"); 
      return urlEmail;
     });


<a class="emailCustomer" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to="+emailAddress+"&su=+invoiceNumber+&body="+customerName+"%2C%0A%0A"+productsList+"%0A%0AEmail+Signature" data-email="{{i.email}}" data-customer="{{i.name}}" data-products="{{i.products}}" target="_blank">
```

Comment: There should be an = between href and the opening quotation marks.

Comment: When you hover over it where, in what context? Where do the variables come from? Can you add some more detail here?

Comment: My general idea is to enter as much content as possible into the body of the email the variable productsList is coming already encoded to replace characters like ()(*^*)_ to encoded

Answer (score 0):

On your a tag the attribute `data-products` is not set, therefore in your click callback `productsList` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the data-products  on this question, but it's on my development I will update it